# how to create multi step registration form in joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla

in my code multi steps are in 5 tabs in form, which tab click they open a input fields.
i `want` a modal box to get info and when click on next button goto next modal box,
following is my code.

```
 <?php
 /**
* @package
* @copyright Copyright (C) 2009 - 2010 Open Source      Matters.                           All rights reserved.
* @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html GNU/LGPL, see                   LICENSE.php
* Contact to : emailtohardik@gmail.com, joomextensions@gmail.com
* Visit : http://www.joomlaextensions.co.in/
**/ 
 defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
 JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip');
 jimport('joomla.html.pane');
 JHTMLBehavior::modal();
 $uri =JURI::getInstance();
 $url= $uri->root();
 $editor =JFactory::getEditor();
 JHTML::_('behavior.calendar');
$option = JRequest::getVar('option','','','string');
 $cntr = JRequest::getVar('tm','','','string');
 $uid = JRequest::getVar('uid','','','int');

$document = JFactory::getDocument();

$link   = JRoute::_('index.php?option='.$option);

jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
$document->addScript($url.'/components/'.$option.'/assets   /js/formvalidation.js');
$document->addScript($url.'/components/'.$option.'/assets    document->addScript($url.'components/'.$option.'/assets/js/stuHover.js');
$document->addScript($url.'components/'.$option.'/assets/js/tab.js');
$document->addStyleSheet($url.'components/'.$option.'/assets/css/style.css');
$document->addStyleSheet($url.'components/'.$option.'/assets/css/pro_dropdown_2.css');

 $model = $this->getModel ( 'fields_data' );
$uid = JRequest::getVar('uid',  0, '', 'int');
$user =  clone(JFactory::getUser());
$res=new extra_field();
$deldata = $model->delfield_data();

$fields_group=$res->list_all_groups();
/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($fields_group);exit;*/
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var must_select     = "<?php echo JText::_( 'MUST_SELECT_ONE_OPTION' );   ?>";
 var please_atselect    = "<?php echo JText::_(  'PLEASE_SELECT_ATLEAST_ONE_OPTION' ); ?>";
     var atselect_one   = "<?php echo JText::_( 'PLEASE_SELECT_ATLEAST_ONE'  ); ?>";
var please_enter    = "<?php echo JText::_( 'PLEASE_ENTER' ); ?>";
var please_select   = "<?php echo JText::_( 'PLEASE_SELECT' ); ?>";
//var please_captcha    = "<?php //echo JText::_(  'PLEASE_ENTER_CAPTCHA_CODE' ); ?>";
</script>

<?php 
if($cntr=="")
{ 
//$pane =& JPane::getInstance('tabs', array('startOffset'=>0)); ?> 
<form action="<?php echo @$link; ?>" method="post" name="adminForm"  id="adminForm" class="modal multi-step" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validatefrm(adminForm)">
 <div class="span10 form-horizontal">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
<?php
$cnt = count($fields_group);
for($i=0;$i<count($fields_group);$i++)
{


?><li><a href="#group<?php echo $i?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo  $fields_group[$i]->group_name;?></a></li><?php 
}

?>
</ul>


<div class="tab-content">
<!--<div class="regi_top">
<?php echo JText::_('VIEW_PROFILE');?>
</div>-->
<?php  
$cnt = count($fields_group);
for($j=0;$j<count($fields_group);$j++)
{

    if($j == '0'){
    $class = "active";
    }else{
    $class = "";
    }

?>
<div  class="tab-pane <?php echo $class;?>" id="group<?php echo $j;?>">
<fieldset class="adminform">
<legend><?php echo $fields_group[$j]->group_name;?></legend>
<?php 


$fields= $res->list_all_field(1,0,0,0,$fields_group[$j]->f_group_id);


?>

<!--<div class="regi_title">
<h3><?php //echo $fields_group[$i]->group_name;?></h3>
</div>
-->


<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="form_table">
<tr>
<td>
<?php 

    $extra=explode("`",$fields);
    echo $extra[0];

?>              
    </table>

</td>
</tr>

</table>


</fieldset>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="rec" id="<?php echo "rec".$i?>" value="<?php  echo $extra[1]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="rec" id="<?php echo "rec1".$i?>" value="<?php echo $extra[2]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="rec" id="<?php echo "rec2".$i?>" value="<?php echo $extra[3]; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" />

 <?php }?>

  <table width="100%" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
                 <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save"   class="button"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>

  <input type="hidden" name="jelive_url" id="jelive_url" value="<?php echo  $url; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field_section" value="<?php echo  $this->detail[0]->id; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="task" value="save" />

<input type="hidden" name="view" value="fields_data" />
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="<?php echo $option;?>" />

  </form>
  <?php }
   ?>
```

i download the multistep registration form in bootstrap. and i use for this but i got error.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use RS Forms for doing that? It has an option to do this and you can easily connect it to the Joomla database (it allows you to add PHP actions when a page is submitted).